# Allocating memory for big program in C

Tags: c, memory-management, for-loop, file-io, matrix

The problem is that the .exe file stops if the input file of at least 20 lines;
When I exclude the 4  big `for loops` that contain operations with the following matrices:

```
int rounded_marks[42][100];
int reassessed[22][k];
int averagecounter[14][k];
```

...program works fine. 
Termination of .exe comes when I these big loops are added (I tired to unite them together, but then there will be extremely big loop, and the same .exe termination).

Total number of lines of each `for loop` is almost 300  in the code.

Can you please check whether the memory allocated is enough for doing operations?

Should I allocate memory for the matrices? How should it look like?

Thank You for the attention.

P.S. I can't debug, no software available on the PC's (installation prohibited):(

`input.dat` is multiline csv file.

Here is the `.c` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)

    {
    int lines_allocated = 100;
    int max_line_len = 150;
    double c[42][1000]={0};
    int print;

    char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);
    if (words==NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (1).\n");
        exit(1);
        }

    FILE *fp = fopen("input.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file.\n");
        exit(2);
        }

    int i;
    for (i=0;1;i++)
        {
        int j;

        if (i >= lines_allocated)
            {
            int new_size;

            new_size = lines_allocated*2;
            words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);
            if (words==NULL)
                {
                fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
                exit(3);
                }
            lines_allocated = new_size;
            }
        words[i] = malloc(max_line_len*sizeof(*(words[i])));
        if (words[i]==NULL)
            {
            fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (3).\n");
            exit(4);
            }
        if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
            break;

        for (j=strlen(words[i])-1;j>=0 && (words[i][j]=='\n' || words[i][j]=='\r');j--)

        words[i][j]='\0';
        }

    int j;
    int k=i; // k is number of lines
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {

        char *pptr = words[j];
        int l;
        for (l = 0; l < 42; l++)
        {
            char *ptr = strchr(pptr, ',');
            if (ptr) 
            {
                *ptr = 0;
                c[l][j] = atof(pptr);
                pptr = ptr + 1;
            }
            else if (isdigit(*pptr)) 
            {
                c[l][j] = atof(pptr);
            }
        }    
    }

    int rounded_marks[42][100];
    int averagecounter[14][k];
    int reassessed[22][k];
    for (j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
             //doing some complicated operations for 1st time
    }
    for (j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
             //doing some complicated operations for 2nd time
    }
    for (j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
             //doing some complicated operations for 3rd time
    }
    for (j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
             //doing some complicated operations for 4th time
    }
}
```

Comment: "Someone debug this for me" probably won't get you anywhere… Have you at least checked if the code you posted manifests the error?

Comment: You posted a lot of code which you say does not cause any problem and then you removed the part that causes the problem (the 4 for loops) basically completely. Also you gave a lower but no upper limit for `k`, which is likely relevant.

Comment: Just some general advise: Don't use fixed buffer sizes. Simply don't. Unless you can *prove* that your limit *can never be exceeded*. Allocate dynamic memory to fit your needs, always. This will avoid tons of hidden bugs that just wait for large enough input to bite you. And every single one *will* eventually bite you.

Comment: IMHO: If software installation is prohibited, then compiling violates that prohibition.

Comment: @millimoose debug is not necessary, i know it comes out of memory if i exceed number of lines. Thing i ask is how to allocate that memory for matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most implementations have a relatively small limit on the size of a stack frame, so you should not try to allocate large arrays as local variables. However, static arrays and the heap can be very large. So move your declaration of `c` out of main and make it a global static variable.

In the case of variables whose sizes are determined at run time, like the arrays dependent on `k`, you should allocate the on the heap using `malloc()`.

Comment: He can't move all the arrays, as `k` is variable.  Dynamic allocation using `malloc` will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am more of an ObjC kinda guy, but the first loop :

```
for (i=0;1;i++)
```

Isn't that going to be running forever (since 1 is always true) and eventually run out of memory because the first loop allocates memory?

Comment: They have a break-condition:

    `if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
            break;`